# How to get a button to actually appear on screen?

Tags: java, button, awt

I am new to programming and I am currently stuck on a minor issue. I have looked up on my own how to create a button, how to use all the methods and what not, but what I am confused on, is how to actually get the button to appear on the screen. This may be something extremely easy that I just don't understand. But can somebody help me? I have created 3 buttons. `

```
Button balance = new Button("Check Balance");
Button deposit = new Button("Deposit");
Button withdraw = new Button("Withdraw");

System.out.println("1. " + balance.getLabel());
System.out.println("2. " + deposit.getLabel());
System.out.println("3. " + withdraw.getLabel());
System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
```

I am simply confused on how to get the button appear on the screen! Thank you .

Comment: If there is a parent container, add this button to it, say panel.add(withdraw)

Comment: Your newbie-ness is glaring.  That is okay, but your issues are larger then what can be solved here.  Why not search for a simple GUI tutorial.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to

1. Use Swing, not AWT
2. Thus create Swing JButton objects, not Button.
3. Create a JPanel, add your JButtons in the JPanel
4. Add your JPanel to your JFrame before displaying it
5. You're just guessing at this and this never works. Please read [the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html) as this is all explained there.

Comment: 3) , 4) are for special reason that has to be in a `JPanel` ? [The Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: @nachokk: if he adds his buttons directly to his JFrame, which uses BorderLayout by default, without using constants, he will only display the last button added. JPanel at least uses a FlowLayout by default which may be better for his purposes.

Comment: nice answer :) i just want to know why you add it to a panel , +1

Answer (score 3):

Here's an ugly (but short) way to do it -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JButton balance = new JButton("Check Balance");
    JButton deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
    JButton withdraw = new JButton("Withdraw");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(balance, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(withdraw, BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel.add(deposit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The buttons must be placed on a `JFrame`. In a nutshell, `JFrame` is the basic container or window used for Java Swing applications.
public class ButtonExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton balance = new JButton("Check Balance");
            JButton deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
            JButton withdraw = new JButton("Withdraw");

            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(balance);
            frame.add(deposit);
            frame.add(withdraw);

            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: @nachokk What is the logic behind not extending JFrame?  Composition over inheritance?  Just curious, I'm from the J2EE world and have only started looking deeper at Swing.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but there's no need for the extension as you're simply using a plain vanilla JFrame. You could substitute JFrame for ButtonExample in your main method and it would work. Extending JFrame just confuses.

Comment: It's not J2EE or Swing it's OOP. Do you have any reason to extend JFrame? are you overriding something? are you giving it more functionality? It's not composition over inheritance cause you don't have to have any property.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the explanation.  Not sweating the downvote, I learn more from the downvotes than the upvotes.

Comment: And to win my upvote wrap your call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable)..` in that way you ensure that is running in the `EDT`.

Comment: @nachokk Should now compile, I went outside the IDE on those edits.  Thanks for the EDT suggestion.  I was aware of it but hadn't gotten around to researching it (currently writing my first major swing app for experience).  If an application were not running on the EDT thread, would repaints of the GUI appear choppy and sometimes fail, blacking out the screen?  For example, if I added some new components through an `ActionListener`?